# Django: Updating and Deleting objects using Django Views

Tags: django, django-views

The task which I am trying to achieve is to give the power to the logged-in user to update and delete their contact list via Django views. I coded all the templates and views.py functionality but has not been able to proceed forward.

Here is what I was able to achieve:

"views.py":

```
@login_required
def update_contact(request,contact_id=1):

    current_user = request.user.get_username()
    user = User.objects.filter(username=current_user).first()
    output = UserContacts.objects.filter(current_user_id=user.id)
    count = output.count()

    contact_obj =get_object_or_404(UserContacts,id = contact_id)

    form = UserContactForm()

    if request.method == "POST": 

        form = UserContactForm(request.POST,instance=contact_obj)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request) 
        else:
            print('Error Form Invalid')

    my_dict = {'output':output,'form':form}

    return render(request,'basic_app/update.html',my_dict)
```

Here is my template for update.html for updating contact:

```
{%extends 'basic_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome to update contact page</h1>
    <br />
    {% if output %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </thead>
        {% for contact in output %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ contact.first_name}}</td>
            <td><a href="{%url 'basic_app:update_contact' contact.id    %}">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

{% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        No contact records found!
    </div>
{% endif %}

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

URLS.Py:

```
app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
    url(r'^user_login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    url(r'^new_contact/$',views.new_contact,name='new_contact'),
    url(r'^view_contacts/$',views.view_contacts,name='view_contacts'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<contact_id>[\d]+)$',views.update_contact,name='update'),
    url(r'^delete/$',views.delete_contact,name="delete")
]
```

[Here is the error I am currently stuck with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpw3e.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the question you have put two times your `views.py` and forgot to put the `update.html`

Comment: How should I update my question?

Comment: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58766032/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py` the name of the update url is `update`:

```
url(r'^update/(?P<contact_id>[\d]+)$',views.update_contact,name='update')
```

But in your template your are using `update_contact` as name.

```
<td><a href="{%url 'basic_app:update_contact' contact.id    %}">Edit</a></td>
```

Try first to change the name in the template:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'basic_app:update' contact.id %}">Edit</a></td>
```